# Wordpress login without password

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I would like for my users to be able to login just by entering their username without password and without 2 factor authentification (no registration possible)

I know it's not good practice, but access to the website will be only possible from a specific location so there is no security issue.

I have found the following code [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_auth_cookie/)

```
// First get the user details
$user = get_user_by('login', $username );

// If no error received, set the WP Cookie
if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) )
    {
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID ); // Set the current user detail
        wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID ); // Set auth details in cookie
        $message = "Logged in successfully";
    } else {
        $message = "Failed to log in";
    }

echo $message;
```

But i have no idea how and where to implement.

Could i just give everybody the same dummy password and fill it automatically/hidden? Again security is not an issue here, we just want the user to log in to track activity later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to do what i was looking for!
Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is the final code:

1. add if statement to see if the user is already login
2. create a very simple form
3. add if statement to see if the form is submitted
4. set current user and auth cookie

The code is not perfect but it will do the work!
Thanks again!

```
<?php 
    global $user_id;
    global $wpbd; 
    if (!$user_ID){

        if($_POST){ //when form is submitted
            $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['username']);
            $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
            if ( $user === false ) {
                    echo 'no'; // add error message
            } else {
                    //user id exists
                    wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
                    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
                    
                    // redirect to admin-area:
                wp_redirect( home_url() );
                    exit();
            }
        } else {
        
            // user is not log in ?>
        <form method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="username">User ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="userame" name="username" placeholder="User ID">
            </p>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Log IN</button>
            </p>
        </form>
        <?php }
        } else {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
        }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
function auto_login_user() {

    if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        return;
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['user_id_ak']) && $_REQUEST['user_id_ak'] > 0){
        $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id_ak'];
        wp_set_current_user($user_id);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
        wp_redirect( admin_url() );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'auto_login_user' );
```

Comment: Thanks, i try your code by adding it to the function.php, but it didnt do anything. I try to log in without the password and got an error message saying password is required. Maybe i dont implement it the right way ?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to login via URL (not exactly what you want, but you may find it useful).

Place the following code at the very beginning of functions.php (you can find it in your theme folder), right after "<?php":

```
if( isset($_GET['username']) and $_GET['pass'] ) {
$user = get_user_by('login', $_GET['username']);

if ( $user && wp_check_password( $_GET['pass'], $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login);
    // redirect to admin-area:
    wp_redirect( admin_url() );
    // redirect to home-page
    // wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}

wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
```

Login URL => https://SITENAME.XXX/wp-admin?username=XXXXX&pass=XXXXX

Please note you can choose where users will be directed.

Comment: thanks, your code worked but as i still need password with this solution it doesnt really help my issue

Comment: Ok, just set the PW equal to USERNAME for every user :-)

Comment: Hello! Your way of setting current and auth cookie help me a lot and i finally found away to do the job! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

After struggling to write my own code for "Wordpress login without password," I found a plugin at https://www.codester.com/items/44774/keypass-wordpress-login-without-password that I quickly installed and it worked perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35111665)